# Conditional Variable with Grid Field

Tags: conditionals, grid

I've got a navigation structure where I'm using the Title as the main navigation menu item and then using grid for any submenu items.  So what I basically want to do is something like this:

```
{if "{submenu:field_total_rows}" == "0"}{if:else}Show the submenu{/if}
```

I've tried multiple variations on the above row - but both empty and non-empty submenus are behaving the same way. I'm sure its just a syntax issue but I can't find what is is.

Answer (score 5):

If `submenu` is the grid fieldtype name, then all you need is:

```
{if submenu:total_rows > 0}submenu contents{/if}
```

You may need to add quotes and brackets around the condition if the above doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I tried a billion combinations as well. This is how I used it for meta data (functional):

```
{if articles_seo_meta_data:total_rows > 0}
    {articles_seo_meta_data}
        {articles_seo_meta_data:meta_title}
    {/articles_seo_meta_data}
{if:else}
    {title}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you had a grid field named 'submenu' with 3 columns in it. One dropdown named 'Target' and two text fields named 'Link', and 'Text'.

You need to see if there are rows first like this:

```
{if submenu:total_rows > 0}
```

Then open the grid field and loop through the rows like this:

```
{submenu}
    Your data...
{/submenu}
```

You would end up with something like this, depending on your markup and what you choose to qualify:

```
{if submenu:total_rows > 0}
    <ul class="subnav">
        {submenu}
            <li class="subnav-item">
                <a {if "{submenu:link"}!=""}href="{submenu:link}"{/if}{if "{submenu:target}"=="External"} target="_blank">{if "{submenu:text}"!=""}{submenu:text}{/if}</a>
            </li>
        {/submenu}
    </ul>
{/if}
```

Comment: @Boshy start a new question and let me know where it is. I'll gladly help.  ;)

Comment: Thanks @Brian Mallett and apologies for slow response (Xmas holdup!). My comment here about my issue seems to have disappeared, no idea why. I've started a new question as I haven't been able to solve the issue.It's here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/27313/grid-conditionals-not-working