# how to check if grid field is empty

Tags: grid

I just need to check if one field artist_gallery:image in a grid field is set, if not the markup should not be rendered.
This syntax {if "{artist_gallery:total_rows}” > 0} or {if artist_gallery:total_rows > 0} is not working ... if there is no image, the markup is rendered.

Any ideas? Thank you!

```
    {if "{artist_gallery:total_rows}" > 0}
 <div id="artistgallery">
  <div class="cycle-slideshow">
   {artist_gallery}
    <img src="{artist_gallery:image}">
   {/artist_gallery}
  </div>
  <div id="adv-custom-pager" ></div>
  <div class="clb"></div>
 </div>
{/if}
```

Comment: What is {artist_gallery:total_rows} printing out in your template?

Comment: I'm using the format:
{if artist_gallery:total_rows >= 2}
and that's working for me

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
{if my_grid_field}
    {my_grid_field}
        Stuff in here if the grid field has rows
    {/my_grid_field}
{/if}
```

Comment: Still not working. Seems such a simple thing.

Comment: {if artist_gallery:image}
      <div id="artistgallery">
       <div class="cycle-slideshow">
        {artist_gallery}
         <img src="{artist_gallery:image}">
        {/artist_gallery}
       </div>
       <div id="adv-custom-pager" class="center external"></div>
       <div class="clb"></div>
      </div>
     {/if}

Comment: If foamcow's suggestion is not working, please put in a support ticket or bug report with EllisLab.

Answer (score 0):

I've now discovered that it is a bug in 2.9.2 and there is a fix, see this question and the answers:
[Grid Conditionals not working](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/27313/grid-conditionals-not-working)