# Can't get Grid conditionals to work in 2.10.3

Tags: conditionals, grid

I've been trying to get a Grid conditional to work (using EE2.10.3) and no matter what I try, it's not working and the page crashes. My grid field is called "projects_video" and I want to output something if it's not empty. Here's what I've been trying so far:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="projects"}
     {if projects_video:total_rows >= 1}
          SOME DATA
     {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Also I've tried:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="projects"}
     {if "{projects_video:total_rows}" >= 1}
          SOME DATA
     {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="projects"}
     {if {projects_video:total_rows} >= 1}
          SOME DATA
     {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="projects"}
     {if projects_video}
          SOME DATA
     {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what eventually worked for me:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="projects" limit="1" disable="categories|member_data|pagination"}
{if '{projects_test:total_rows}' > '0'}
    {exp:vmg_nested:channel:entries channel="projects" limit="1" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" prefix="test"}
        {projects_test}
            {projects_test:text}
        {/projects_test}
    {/exp:vmg_nested:channel:entries}
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Note the single quotes around the braces in the "if" statement.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you could use the basics of:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="projects"}
     {if projects_video}
       {projects_video}
          {projects_video:option}
          {projects_video:option2}
          etc...
       {/projects_video}
     {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The if statement checks that there is something in the Grid field. Note that this will return true even if the user has created a row and put nothing in it.

Comment: Actually, that was the first thing I tried -- sorry I didn't remember to include that in the listing of what I had tried. I've edited now to include that.

Comment: It should work but you need to include the grid tags once inside the conditional. Answer updated!

Comment: You're right that it should work! But unfortunately it doesn't. It doesn't matter what is inside the if statement; it just breaks the thing, and I get "You have an invalid conditional in your template. Please review your conditionals for an unclosed string, invalid operators, a missing }, or a missing {/if}."

Comment: Did you check this post: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/27313/grid-conditionals-not-working

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did and tried out what was there, but unfortunately nothing works.